# Better than O(n!) algorithm for unordered tuple comparison

Tags: c++11

I'm writing a little math library (for interest, no particular goal in mind) and I've come across a little difficulty.  I have an `Addition` class that looks like:

```
    template <class ... Functions>
    struct Addition
    {
        std::tuple<Functions...> functions;
        //...
    };
```

and I would like to implement `operator==` for this class.  Simply returning `functions == o.functions` is no good because, for example, the instantiations `Addition<Sine, Cosine>` and `Addition<Cosine, Sine>` would not compare as equal, but I would like them to.

The current restrictions imposed on functions I create are:

1. A function object must be comparable to any other function object.  This is implemented by adding

   `template <class F>
    bool operator==(F && f) const
    {
        return false;
    }`

   to each function class' definition.
2. Two classes are equal only if they are of the same class.  In other words it is necessary but not sufficient that two classes be the same class to compare as equal.

My solution right now is to do an ordered comparison of the two tuples and then permute one of them and try another ordered comparison and keep permuting and comparing until one returns true.  This method runs in O(n!) time and requires O(n!) template instantiations.

What I would have liked to do is simply find elements that compare equal and then remove them and continue comparing the two sub-tuples.  Unfortunately, since the comparisons have runtime code (in general) you cannot know which elements to remove at compile.  Any solution like this would end up with O(n!) template instantiations, which is also undesirable.

So, is there a way to do an unordered comparison of two tuples (with the above two points, but bonus points if you don't use them) that achieves less than O(n!) running time *and* less than O(n!) template instantiations.

Comment: Force a well defined order.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes can I do that without having to maintain a separate type list?

Comment: Can you have duplicates? I.e. Addition<Sine,Sine> where the 2 elements compare equal? There is a polynomial greedy algorithm: check that the tuples have the same size, and for each element of the first tuple look for its match in the second tuple. If there can be duplicates you have to refine a bit.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes there can be duplicates.

Comment: Sticking with the brutal solutions, you can keep a list of the indices of the elements of the second tuple already matched. Things will still be polynomial in runtime and number of instantiations.

Comment: @GuyGreer You could require each function object to provide a UUID-like object at compile-time (e.g. via a `static constexpr` member function).

Comment: @dyp, I had forgotten about UUIDs, this sounds like the way I'll end up trying.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option would be to use boost fusion [set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/set.html).

Also another advantage over std::tuple is that you get algorithm for boost fusion containers so you can use [fold](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/fold.html) to check if each Function object in a fusion set is contained in other fusion set or not:

```
    template <class ... Functions>
    struct Addition
    {
        boost::fusion::set<Functions...> functions;
        //...


        struct Equal
        {

            typedef boost::fusion::set<Functions...> Functions;
            Functions& functions;

            template<typename T>
            std::enable_if<boost::fusion::has_key<Functions, T>::value, bool> 
            operator()(bool res, T& t) const
            {
                  return res && boost::fusion::at_key<T>(functions) == t;
            }

            template<typename T>
            std::enable_if<!boost::fusion::has_key<Functions, T>::value, bool> 
            operator()(bool res, T& t) const
            {
                return false;
            }

        };

        template <class ... Functions1>
        bool operator==(Addition<Functions1...> that)
        {
            return boost::fusion::fold(true, that.functions, Equal<Functions...>{this.functions});
        };

        ...
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I solved this, but I thought I would share my solution here in case anybody else ever decides to try this crazy thing, they may find this helpful.  Also, perhaps in posting this someone may come along with a simpler solution to the problem than what I found.

I ended up going with dyp's suggestion from the comments of providing a UUID-like object for my classes.
This was a little more difficult than just a numerical identifier for all functions, so for container-functions (Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, etc...) the UUID is their specific identifier followed by the ordered list of the UUIDs of their component functions.

For example:

```
    struct Sine { typedef int_<0> UUID;};
    struct Cosine { typedef int_<1> UUID;};

    template <class ... Functions>
    struct Addition { typedef list<int_<2>, list<Functions::UUID...> UUID;}
```

Reorderable containers (as opposed to, say, Multiplication of Matrix objects) are always reordered to be sorted by their UUIDs so that the UUID of the container-function be the same for classes that are composed of the same functions and different otherwise.

```
    auto f1 = Simplify(Add(Sine{}, Cos{}));
    auto f2 = Simplify(Add(Cosine{}, Sine{}));
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(f2)>::value, "");
    assert(f1 == f2);
```

This also means that UUIDs will be different for non-abelian function-containers with the same functions but in a different order, which is a bonus (and no, I'm not explaining here *how* I actually express that operations are abelian or not).

The comparison then of these container functions is then quite simple, I can just do `functions == o.functions`.